# Blacklist ip that request certain pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess

As many people (i suppose) I have found in my apache log a lot of unauthorized attempts to access my webserver. Among the pattern of URLs found, there is everytime something like "/phpmyadmin".
As this is for shure something impossible to find in my server, what I would like to do is : "If somebody try to access `phpMyAdmin` blacklist its IP and don't botter me anymore"
Does somebody knows how to do that with Apache or maybe another software ?
Thanx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you.

1) Create a filter in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/myapachejail.conf

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = ^.* <HOST> -.*"(:?GET|POST|HEAD) \/(?:\/|)(?:w00tw00t\.at.*|phpMyAdmin.*|whatever.*|anotherone.*\..*)".*

ignoreregex =
```

2) Update your /etc/fail2ban/jail.local including this jail

```
banaction = iptables-multiport

action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
           %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

[apachejail]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = myapachejail
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log #<=== THIS MUST BE YOUR LOG FILE
maxretry = 1 # 1: Paranoid mode, 2: Heavy filter, 5: Ban any scanner
action   = %(action_mwl)
```

3) Check if your filter regexp matches any of the log entries

```
sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/myapachejail.conf

Result:
Lines: 6160 lines, 0 ignored, 108 matched, 6052 missed
```

4) Verify you find /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf

5) Restart fail2ban service

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

6) Check your new jail is running:

```
 sudo fail2ban-client status

Status
|- Number of jail:  5
`- Jail list:       myapachejail,xxxxx,xxx,xxxxx,xxxx
```

7) Check fail2ban log

```
sudo vim /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

2014-07-07 07:32:20,926 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [myapachejail] Ban 198.20.69.74
2014-07-07 08:45:36,153 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [myapachejail] Ban 116.10.191.223

7) Check your iptables is banning:

```
sudo iptables -L -n

REJECT     all  --  198.20.69.74      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  116.10.191.223        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer seems to be **Fail2ban** with a specific configuration.
I have found a post that explain that in detail : [How to protect Apache with Fail2ban](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-protect-apache-with-fail2ban).
If somebody has another interesting solution, please let us know.